# ow to display the number of posts in a category

Tags: categories

how to display how many posts in one category, for example I have the category "mywebsite.com/category/blogger", how to display the number of posts (in numbers) in the "blogger" category

sorry my bad english

Answer (score 1):

There is a default `archive.php` template in all WordPress themes which has a static layout that looks like the blog and which is used any time a category archive is directly accessed using the category link or URL, that is where you have to put your code, in the place that you want.

So, basically you will have to do something like this wihtin the archive.php to get the number of post:

```
$category = get_category($id);
$count = $category->category_count;
```

Then you print it the way you want, echo `"This category has ".$count." posts";`, or something like that.